# Pivotal Greenplum command center is not responding

Tags: greenplum

When i try to reach greenplum command center using web browser.

**Error I Get :**

```
[gpadmin@mdw ~]$ psql -h hostname -p 28080 - U gpmon
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "gpmon" ignored
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "hostname" (IP) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 28080?
```

Why gcc is down ?

**Also checked**

```
[gpadmin@mdw~]$ ps ax | grep gpcmdr
 1578 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep gpcmdr

**Verified the data collection process is running on the Greenplum master** 
[gpadmin@mdw ~]$ ps -ef | grep gpmmon
gpadmin   1659 23646  0 13:53 pts/1    00:00:00 grep gpmmon


[gpadmin@mdw ~]$ gpcmdr --start
Starting instance gpcc...
Greenplum Command Center UI for instance 'gpcc' - [RUNNING on PORT:  28080]
[gpadmin@mdw ~]$
```

Any help on it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are attempting to connect with psql, not a web browser.  http://hostname:28080

Comment: Yes. when i tried to use  $psql -h hostname -p 28080 -U gpmon. getting the same  error

Comment: Also , when i am using as http address hostname:28080 . No UI visible .  basically want to login through greenplum command center web portal.

Comment: Did you start it?  Do you see the process running?

Comment: your ps output shows it is not running.

Comment: Thanks  Jon I just started the instance and it is running  proper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136964/discussion-between-sylphes-and-jon-roberts).